# Is this plastic clip made of polypropylene or polyethylene?

Tags: polymers, materials, identification, adhesion

I am trying to re-attach an automotive clip (painted plastic with a yellow (epoxy?) hard adhesive backing) which secures a trim piece back onto the vehicle's roof sheet metal (unpainted (primed?) area).

[image]

I am thinking of using [Gorilla Glue](https://www.gorillatough.com/product/original-gorilla-glue/), a polyurethane adhesive, which says it bonds many dissimilar surfaces, but specifically says to avoid PP and PE:

> Gorilla Glue will work well on many types of plastic; however, we do not recommend for use on polypropylene (PP) or polyethylene (PE) plastics or any type of rubber with high oil or plasticizer content.

1. Any clues as to whether the clip and backing are PP or PE?
2. General thoughts on whether Gorilla Glue is suitable, or if another type of adhesive would be better?

I realize this isn't the typical question on the Chemistry Stack Exchange Community, but thought the technical chemistry aspect is more suited here than the Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair Community.

Comment: One often can identify PE or PP by the "waxy" feel and appearance. See https://resin-expert.com/en/guide/best-glue-for-polypropylene for gluing PP. However, you might choose an adhesive that handles a variety of materials. Be aware a car roof can get quite hot (so it's doubtful lower-melting PE is used), and the cement would have to handle a wide temperature range.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The clip itself feels very glassy or metallic, maybe partly due to the metallic paint. The yellow backing does have some "waxy" feel, and fingernails can mark it fairly easily. Thanks for the link and PE/PP identification tips. I've applied Gorilla Glue and will test it's strength (doesn't have to be super strong for this application) after letting it cure 1-2 days. If it doesn't hold, I will try JB Weld next since the article suggests epoxy is best.

Comment: As far as question is concerned, edit should be much more thorough for reopening - with details besides photo and improved clarity. Still, I think the answer probably is no, and this glue would probably work. Why? If it's painted then glue should stick too, but for solid answer, solid data are needed.

Comment: @adatum For the record, none of the closers are moderators. It appears the question will be reopened. Personally, I have used [Gorilla Epoxy](https://www.gorillatough.com/product/gorilla-epoxy/) for everything from repairing a cracked rear quarter panel to filling in cracks on bicycle shifter enclosures. A light sanding with high grit sandpaper before application wouldn't hurt. If this doesn't work, JB Weld will - that's the go-to for many bike techs (I was one).

Comment: @ToddMinehardt Thanks for the feedback, epoxy seems most recommended. Still not sure if the clip's backing is PE or PP, but the polyurethane Gorilla Glue is holding solidly.  I did sand the backing with 400 grit sandpaper, but not the vehicle roof. We'll see about the long term and temperature variations. One concern with rigid adhesives and dissimilar surfaces is how they will handle contraction/expansion in winter and summer. Note that Gorilla Glue has better moisture resistance and wider service temperature than Gorilla Epoxy according to the manufacturer's specs.